# FTP Syntax for sending files to Mainframe server retaining the CASE

Tags: ftp, mainframe, outbound

I am trying to FTP a file from windows server to Mainframe. The FTP is successful, but there is a problem with the contents of the FTPed file.
It doesn’t retain the Capital Letters – DAY changed to Day…BEEN changed to Been.

The earlier tool I used to FTP file used a FORMAT(PRINT UC) command to take care of this.
I want to know what is the corresponding syntax in FTP to retain the CAPS ON/OFF while FTPing.

I did research over Google to find the FTP replacement for Format (Print UC) and got the following syntax, but it didn’t work.

SET PROCESS/PARSE_STYLE=TRADITIONAL

Reference URLs:
http://compgroups.net/comp.os.vms/changing-uppercase-filenames-into-lowercase/519832
http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/73final/6536/6536pro_003.html

Comment: What kind of "mainframe" are you sending files to, and what operating system is running on it?

Comment: z/os is the mainframe and i think it is 1.05 operating system.

Comment: @NealB...Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, I've never heard of anything like that in FTP itself.You'd best add the output of your ftp session, desensitised.

Comment: @BillWoodger...Is there any particular format to make the content desensitised?

Comment: Best I can tell `PARSE_STYLE` is a DCL directive for file name (not content) case conversion under HP VMS (originally DEC VAX VMS) so would not apply in a z/os environment. FTP can perform code page conversion and that might be able to explain all upper case filpping to lower case but would not explain positional character conversion (e.g. first character of every word only). I have never heard of a problem like this with FTP. Are there any other processes involved in this transfer - besides FTP? Sorry I can't help you any fruther on this one.

Comment: @sammy, FTP has nothing which would do this. Have a look at your source file. It should already have the formatting in. You'll have to look for something happening before the FTP.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting to the mainframe you might issue a "**quote help**" command (instead of simply "help") to see if there are options listed on the remote machine that are available that you are not taking advantage of.  Frankly, the symptoms you describe seem more relevant to actions that a text editor might display than something that FTP would be doing. Perhaps your viewer is manipulating the text via preset profile options AFTER the file has transmitted?  That's just a guess.